# Is it possible to change the background-position while keeping "top right"?

Tags: css, background-position

I have an object that have a background with background-position "top right"

I want to move this background-position up by 10px (on hover), but as soon I change the values, the new value is inserted from the 0,0 point (top left) but I want (top right)

Is there any 100% CSS solution to this?

Comment: if you only want this statically why not make a version of the image with 10px shaved off the top?

Comment: I want to move it by 10px only on hover, I will update my question to make it clearer

Comment: Why not simply `background-postion: 10px right;`, or `background-postion: -10px right;` (depending on what you're trying to do)?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been the other way around: `background-postion: right -10px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
div{
    height:450px;
    width:450px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-image:url(//IMAGE);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 0;
}

div:hover{
    background-position: 100% -10px;
}
```

Giving it a `background-position:100% 0` sets it to the top right corner.  Then minus `10px` from the height on hover.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Teyfj/

*Height, width, and border are for example only*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background image of a particular element on hover:

```
#my_element {
    background-image: url(/path/to/image);
]
#my_element:hover {
    background-image: url(/path/to/another/image);
]
```

So you could make a second image with 10px off the top and this should work, I guess with `body` instead of `#my_element`.

Comment: I already knew that, but I like to use only 1 background and then move the position because there is a delay when downloading the 2nd background and I hate it. (I know there are work-arounds like pre-cache them, but I really just prefer to use 1 background)